# Problem with Plot of Solution for NDSolve

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

I'm trying to plot the solution of an equation using NDSolve. For some reason nothing shows up in the plot. I checked the output of the interpolating function and it doesn't look like there is anything wrong with the data - though I could be wrong - so I'm just trying to figure out what is going on.

```
     q2 = NDSolve[{u'[ϕ] == -Sqrt[3 - 2 u[ϕ] ArcSech[1/u[ϕ]]/Sqrt[u[ϕ]^2 - 1]], 
                  u[1.494706195984861] == 3.208921901232091}, 
                  u, {ϕ, 1.494706195984861, 20}]
```

Then when I use PolarPlot to plot the function, nothing appears:

```
s2 = PolarPlot[Evaluate[1/u[ϕ] /. q2], {ϕ, 1.494706195984861, 14.708465676522565},
               PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> Thick]
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: it is complex. Try `s2 = PolarPlot[Evaluate[Re[1/u[\[Phi]] /. q2]], {\[Phi], 1.494706195984861, 14.708465676522565}, PlotRange -> All, 
  PlotStyle -> Thick]` ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/hxgI5.png)

Comment: And the imaginary part isn't negligible ...

Comment: @Nasser, Thank you!

Comment: @belisarius, Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, your result is complex. You could split real and imaginary part and plot them together:

```
PolarPlot[Evaluate[{Re[#], Im[#]} & @@ (1/u[\[Phi]] /. q2)], 
  {\[Phi], 1.494706195984861, 14.708465676522565}, 
  PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> Thick]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Perfect. Thank you!